# how do i convert list in reverse order in excel sheet

Tags: excel

I have written some values in column and I want to make it in reverse order.

Comment: In what programming language do you want to do this? VBA? Something else?

Answer (score 24):

1. Insert a column next to the column you want to sort
2. From the top cell in the new column, add 1 to the first cell, 2 to the 2nd cell, etc. until you reach the bottom cell.
3. Select both your original column and the new numbered column
4. Go to Data > Sort
5. Sort by the new column, descending.
6. You're done!

*NOTE: If you want to know how to do this using VBA code, please specify as such in your quesiton.  Otherwise, this answers your question and it really belongs on superuser.com*

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you want to invert the range E1:E6 and place the inverted list in range F1:F6.

Enter this array formula in F1. (This is an array formula so you must press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

```
=OFFSET($E$1:$E$6,MAX(ROW($F$1:$F$6))-ROW(),0)
```

Then select the entire F1:F6 range, and use Fill Down (Home tab / Editing) to copy this formula down into all the cells in the range F1:F6.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an extra column which numbers 1,2,3,.... N. Next you use this column to sort the area that includes your data in reverse order (descending).

Answer (score 1):

Why use the Offset or an array formula?
Why not use "=($E1-(MAX($E$2:$E$)+1))*-1", enter this in Cell F1 and copy down.
No array formula, no Offset, cleaner, and simplier, IMHO.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).